# How to emit an event with data when testing Angular (ng-Grid) with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, ng-grid

assuming I have the following listener:

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function(event, data){
  var entity;

  if(data && data.targetScope && data.targetScope.row) {
    entity = data.targetScope.row.entity;
  } else {
    entity = event.targetScope.row.entity;
  }

  entity.projectId = $scope.projectId;

  GanttCommunicator.updateActivity(entity);
});
```

How do I test the case in which the event comes in with event.targetScope... ?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a controller which is higher up the scope hierarchy than ng-grid. You want to $emit an event called ngGridEventEndCellEdit to simulate what ng-grid will do.

Then you just verify the changes that you expect to see. You can do this using jasmine spies. See the code below for an example on how to do this.

```
describe('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function(){
  var scope;
  var childScope;
  var GanttCommunicator;
  beforeEach(function($rootScope,$controller,GanttCommunicator){
    // child of $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // child of scope
    childScope = scope.$new();
    $controller('YourControllerWithListener', {
      $scope : scope
    });
  });

  it('should handle an event $emitted up from a child scope', function(){

    scope.projectId = 12341;
    // .and.callThrough() is jasmine2.0 syntax. jasmine 1.3 is a bit different
    spyOn(scope,'ngGridEventEndCellEdit').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(GanttCommunicator,'updateActivity');

    var myPayload = {
      whatsThis: 'the payload',
      targetScope: {
        row: {
          entity: 'blah'
        }
      }
    };

    // $emit only goes up, which is why we need a child scope
    childScope.$emit('ngGridEventEndCellEdit',myPayload);

    // See what an angular event is composed of here ... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on
    var expectedEvent = {...};


    //expect that the spied on functions have been called with the correct values.
    expect(scope.ngGridEventEndCellEdit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedEvent,myPayload);
    expect(GanttCommunicator.updateActivity).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
      projectId: scope.projectId
    }));

  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Jesse. But that payload is coming inside of "data" in my example, which from that I can simulate the value of data.targetScope.row.entity

My question is about how to simulate the following value in my example: event.targetScope.row.entity

Or maybe I didn't fully understand your answer?

Comment: @Zoh, I realize I made an error.     expect(scope.ngGridEventEndCellEdit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedEvent,myPayload)  is this changed line.  The payload/data will run through your listener code in this test. I have not tested it but this is approximately how you'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this. The simple way is just to mock

```
var entity = { id: 1, name: 'first' };
var row = { entity: entity };
var targetScope = { row: row };
window.event = { 
  targetScope: targetScope
};
```